# Toggle IIS 7.5 Authentication "Anonymous Authentication" with Powershell 3.0?

Tags: authentication, iis, powershell

I'd like to toggle the Anonymous Authentication (Enabled/Disabled) setting found in IIS Manager (7.5, Windows 7), Default Web Site / My Website - Authentication / Anonymous Authentication using Powershell.

I'm not looking for something that alters a web.config file, but does exactly what IIS Manager does.

I've tried Set-WebConfiguration and Set-WebConfigurationProperty but not gotten close.

Can anyone provide an example?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try the `Set-WebConfigurationProperty` cmdlet:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -Filter system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication `
                              -PSPath MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST `
                              -Location 'Default Web Site' `
                              -Name Enabled `
                              -Value $true
```

Comment: Works perfectly.  What thru me was the -PSPath.  Thanks much.

Comment: @Shay can you tell how can I modify "Feature Delegation" using power shell. I want to change "Authentication - Anonymous+ to Read/Write. Thanks.